# Manually adding FontAwesome in swift iOS

Tags: swift

I need to use FontAwesome in my swift project.

I am referring following link:https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

Using CocoaPods i am getting lot of error and so have to setup FontAwesome manually

The link does not mention in detail on how to do this.

I am using Xcode 8.1

Please help

Comment: `i am getting lot of error` What errors?

Comment: What errors do you get when adding with cocoa pods?

Comment: I am getting 15 errors and all errors are inside FontAwesome.swift file....Few examples of errors are:/Users/MacBook/Documents/workspace/Meeting/meetingmayhem/Pods/FontAwesome.swift/FontAwesome/FontAwesomeView.swift:31:54: Extraneous argument label 'code:' in call

Comment: I think your library is in Swift 2, and since you're using Swift 3 (with Xcode 8) it can't work. You should use a Swift 3 version of the library if it exists.

Comment: @Eric...Hmm good point...but no where in the link i am referring talks abt which all version it supports..To give you some insight...this project was working good..just recently i updated my Xcode to 8.1 and then this error is throwing up...i have used it in lot of places and not sure how to manage this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the font files (FontAwesome.otf) to your `Info.plist`? (You also need to add the file to your project)  It might be because of that.

[image]

That way you can use the font without using the swift class they provide.

```
let font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: fontSize)!
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to go if you dont want to use pod. Download the project from github. Then go to downloaded file and drag FontAwesome.xcodeproj into your project like this.

[image]

Then, switch to your project settings, choose your target and in General tab find, "Linked frameworks and library", drag FontAwesome.framework from FontAwesome->Products into this section.

[image]

Simply import it to your class like this,

```
import UIKit
import FontAwesome


public class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 100)
        label.text = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .github)
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.frame = CGRect(x:60, y: 60, width: 200, height: 300)


    }
}
```

Comment: i already have a project and not sure i can include FontAwesome.xcodeproj in my project.

Comment: Well, then you should use Pod otherwise. You include the project just in order to link framework against your project. So, it does not merely do anything.

Comment: @Sandeep..i have been trying from last 2 days to make it working using Pods..but it is throwing me about 15 errors as mentioned above